# change an image using jquery with no CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery

As part of the checkout process of a site im working i can edit the CSS to style the page but there are a few links that are images that i would like to change.

Basicly i need to change every instance of:

```
<img src="images/button.png">
```

within the page to

```
<img src="http://somewhereelse.com/images/newbutton.png">
```

There is no css ID or class attached to this image and there is no way of adding one.

Can this be done with JS or JQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jquery:

```
$('img[src=images/button.png]').attr('src','http://somewhereelse.com/images/newbutton.png');
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score -1):

```
$('img').attr('src', 'http://somewhereelse.com/images/newbutton.png');
```

or

```
$('img[src=images/button.png]').attr(
'src', 'http://somewhereelse.com/images/newbutton.png'
);
```

Comment: I think the OP only wants to change images with the particular `src=images/button.png` and not *all* the images

Comment: This way it might change unneeded images.